# UIBezierPath Scaling all coordinate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

I want to change all coordinates or points contained in `UIBezierPath` or in `CGPath`. I want to multiply points to some value.

I found `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(transX,transY)`
but it actually increases or decreases the value. How can I multiply all values?

Comment: "Translation" means that on offset is *added* to all x/y coordinates.  Perhaps CGAffineTransformMakeScale is what you are looking for?

Comment: Ok @MartinR sorry for translation word but i need to multiply every point, is there any solution for it ..

Comment: How did you eventually solve your issue?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect with your answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextScaleCTM) and [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/) documentation:

**Swift**

```
func CGContextScaleCTM(_ c: CGContext?, _ sx: CGFloat, _ sy: CGFloat)
```

Unless [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15936794/218152), in which case this question is a duplicate.