# Scale down a UIView to fit in screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I developed my application for iPad , now I need to optimize it for iPhones , I used `Auto layout` and `constraint` for other View controllers and works fine , but in main menu I have an `UIView` which it has lots of images without orderly placed on view. This view added as subview in `UIScrollview` which you can scroll it. Exactly like this :

[image]

I tried to change its scale with this code , but no success :

```
sceneView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8 , y: 0.8)
```

Result :
[image]

Is there any simple way to scale it down and fit it to device's screen ?

Comment: @meaning-matters it doesn't fit correctly and buttons not work !

Comment: Indeed. Why not scale the image views? Perhaps too obvious, but if you have less space what else can you do.

Comment: @meaning-matters
That would be so wrong it is for example 50 images layer per layer which animates with parallel effect

Comment: Are the images moving, do you render de view yourself or what is the deal? Is it a static image and do you want to crop it / shrink it? What is the final picture you would want to accomplish.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643626/scale-cgpath-to-fit-uiview

Comment: What would be wrong? I think you should supply more context to your question.

Comment: @meaning-matters It is simple scaling down UIView To fit iPhone screen that is all I want to do

Comment: did you try the CGAffineTransform but with less than 0.8? lets say 0.4?

Comment: First question is why you use scrollview if you want to fit to screen ?  .It is only matters `sceneView` size. if you decrease it . you can get fit to iphone size screen.

Comment: @MikeAlter Just need to fit its height, still want to scroll it

Comment: Did you try to set `sceneView` Height = scrollview Height ? as well as content size height =  sceneView` Height

Comment: Is it added in Interface Builder or code?

Comment: @agibson007  interface builder